# I am trying to execute REST API within powershell using invoke-restmethod/invoke-webrequest but failed when I pass Json inputs

Tags: json, powershell, curl, invoke-command

I am trying to execute REST API within powershell using invoke-restmethod/invoke-webrequest but failed when I pass Json inputs. It works with CURL command.

```sh
curl -v --user admin:password -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -d "@C:\data\test.json" -X POST http://10.11.60.88:8081/artifactory/api/distribute
```

Test.json contents are as below

```
{
    "targetRepo" : "ECSDigital_Bintray", 
    "packagesRepoPaths" : ["SNOW/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/3.3.9/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar"] 
}
```

I wrote the below PowerShell and it gives me series of errors:

```
$user = "admin"

$pass = "password"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $user -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($pass, $secpasswd)

$postParams = @{targetRepo='SNOW';packagesRepoPaths='["org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/3.3.9/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar"]'}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://10.11.60.88:8081/artifactory/api/distribute" -Credential $cred -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $postParams
```

```
Error: Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

I have tried some combinations of json inputs but no go. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, the following way solved my issues, there was need of additional ""

```
$params = @{

uri = $ARTIFACTORY_PROTOCOL+"://"+$ARTIFACTORY_IP+":"+$ARTIFACTORY_PORT+"/artifactory/api/distribute";

Method = 'POST';

Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME):$($ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD)"));"Accept" = 'application/json';"Content-Type" = 'application/json'}

#body = @{""targetRepo"" : ""$DISTRIBUTION_REPOSITORY"", ""packagesRepoPaths"" : ""$ARTIFACTORY_PATH""} 

}

$json = "{
           ""targetRepo"":""$DISTRIBUTION_REPOSITORY"",
           ""packagesRepoPaths"":[""$ARTIFACTORY_PATH""]
         }"

$var = invoke-restmethod @params -Body $json
echo $var
```

Answer (score 0):

While you discovered a solution here, I'd like to explain what was wrong with your original code and offer some improvements to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436054/584676), to help others who may find it and not understand everything that was changed (it was more than just needing extra quotes as [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436054/584676) implies).

> A word of warning, this answer is long and also explains some constructs in detail that were in your [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436054/584676) which I ended up removing from the final code. If you want to see the final code, I've labelled the section as such at the bottom of this answer.

---

## Main Issue: The `$postParams` was in the wrong format

The main issue was that the remote service was expecting JSON, but you provided something different for `$postParams`: a PowerShell hashtable. This gets converted to a string in the end but not in JSON format. While you *can* type out the JSON or write a function to generate a JSON object, defining your arguments as a hashtable allows for easier maintenance and readability within your script. You can easily convert the object to JSON when it comes time to `POST` it by using the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet. There is a suitable example in the final code at the end of this answer.

> Note: `-Depth 100` makes `ConvertTo-Json` convert nested objects (up to 100, this is the limit) to JSON. Otherwise it will stop and provide a `.ToString()` representation of the value at the default depth of 3. If you have deeply nested objects, I recommend providing `-Depth` but this is not required in your use current example.

---

### Suggested: Make use of `Invoke-RestMethod`

As you discovered can also make use of `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest` so you can get a proper object returned to work with instead of having to parse the response content yourself. `ConvertFrom-Json` makes this relatively painless, but `Invoke-RestMethod` is just one more way to simplify your code. This is already used within your current answer.

---

### Suggested: Use variable expansion and sub-expressions instead of string concatenation

String concatenation makes a script or program consume more memory than it needs to as the string is copied multiple times for each `+`. To use variable expansion, simply reference your variable within a double-quoted string (single quoted strings are literal strings and will not expand as the `$` is not treated as a variable reference token). You can see how this is done in the final code at the bottom of this answer.

> Note: With variable substitution, sometimes you will need to change `"$var"` to `"${var}"`. This is an escape sequence separating the variable name from other tokens in the string. You can see this when I reference `${ARTIFACTORY_IP}` and `${ARTIFACTORY_PROTOCOL}` below, as both have an immediately proceeding `:` would be interpreted as part of a variable name.

Using sub-expressions within a string is similar, but makes use of the `$()` operator instead of directly referencing a variable name or using `${}`. This is different because rather than inserting the value of a variable, it instead computes a full PowerShell expression and returns the result as a string. The returned value is then rendered into the string.

**As I've removed the relevant code using sub-expressions from the final code at the bottom, here's an example of how they are used**:

```
$name = 'Bender'
$age = 999
"Next year, $name will be $($age + 1)"
"$name's name has $($name.Length) letters in it"
```

---

### Suggested: Use here-strings instead of multi-line strings

Here-strings are represented by `@"`, followed by lines of text (in which variables can be expanded and sub-expressions processed), and then followed by a final line beginning with `"@`. ***This final line cannot be prepended by any whitespace regardless of where it lies in your script***). This has the benefit of not needing to escape your quotes within the string content itself, and best signals your intent of multiline content to other maintainers.

As I've removed the multi-line string altogether in the final code, here is an example of defining here-strings:

```
$name = 'Bender'
$age = 999

# Regardless of where in the script it's used,
# the final `"@` MUST start at the first column
# of the line or it won't be parsed as the end of
# the here-string
$hereString = @"
Name: $name
Age: $age
"@
```

> Note: Like regular strings, there is also a literal variant of the here-string using `@'` and `'@` (note the single-quotes). These are also interpreted literally so no variable expansion or processing of sub-expressions will occur. You still have the benefit of not needing to escape single-quotes.

---

### Suggested: Hashtable definition tips

When you define a hashtable `@{}` in PowerShell, you do not need to end each line with a `;` if each key is defined on its own line. I have removed the unnecessary `;`s in the final code. You also don't need to wrap keys in quotes unless:

- The key name uses a token character which PowerShell attempts to parse as syntax

  - Including but not limited to `-` or whitespace
- The key name is partially determined by the value of another variable

  - A key name does **not** need to be wrapped if the key name is to be the exact value of another variable

**As I've removed the `Accept` and `Content-Type` parameters from the final code** (next part explains why), here is a more complete example of hashtable definition than what is in the final code at the end:

```
$keyName = 'Catchphrase'

$hashtable = @{
  # Key name does not need to be quoted
  Name = 'Bender'
  Age = '999'

  # This key name would render to 'Catchphrase', without the quotes
  $keyName = 'Bite my pontiferous persnickity PowerShell'

  # Key name needs to be quoted if parseable PowerShell tokens appear in the name
  'Content-Type' = 'Key name contains a hyphen'
  'This key name contains spaces' = 'Key name contains spaces'

  # This key name would render to 'AnotherCatchphrase' without the quotes
  "Another$keyName" = 'Antiquiqing'
}
```

---

### Suggested: Use native parameters on `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of defining the headers yourself

Finally, you shouldn't need to define `Accept: "application/json"` in the header, nor do you need to provide `Content-Type: "application/json"` in the header either. Simply use the `-ContentType` parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest` and set it to 'application/json'. I've made this change in the final code at the bottom of this answer.

> Note: There may be some nuanced situations where you need to set `Accept` to a different format than `ContentType` but I don't believe Artifactory falls into this category.

---

## Final Code

Using the code from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436054/584676) as a base, we can improve it like so:

```
# Define json parameters
$jsonParams = @{
  targetRepo = "$DISTRIBUTION_REPOSITORY"
  packagesRepoPaths = @("$ARTIFACTORY_PATH")
}

$params = @{

  Uri = "${ARTIFACTORY_PROTOCOL}://${ARTIFACTORY_IP}:$ARTIFACTORY_PORT/artifactory/api/distribute"
  Method = 'POST'
  Headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("{$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME}:$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD")))
  }
  ContentType = 'application/json'
  Body = $jsonParams | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
}

# I also moved -Body to $params
$var = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```